# What is the proper way to generate mipmaps

Tags: opengl, textures

In a recent tutorial, I came across this to generate mipmaps for 'textureObject'

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureObject);
glBindSampler(0, samplerObject);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

I want to question the usage of

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindSampler(0, samplerObject);
```

before calling 'glGenerateMipmap'. Because I get the same result as before, if i comment out these 2 lines.

Are these lines present just to make sure that the right texture unit and sampler is bound before generating mipmaps?

or
these lines actually tell which texture unit to choose and what kind of sampling to do to generate mipmaps?

what will happen if I skip these 2 lines?

Answer (score 2):

from [glGenerateMipmap reference](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGenerateMipmap.xml)

> Specifies the texture target of the active texture unit to which the texture object is bound whose mipmaps will be generated

and more

> Mipmap generation replaces texel array levels level base + 1 through q with arrays derived from the level base array, regardless of their previous contents. All other mimap arrays, including the level base array, are left unchanged by this computation.

This way, if you use

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureObject);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1); // <<
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

You will get mipmaps for different texture object (if texture unit 1 has other texture object bound)

Regarding **samplers**: they can override `GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL`​ and `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL​` so it is also important to use a proper sampler object.

See a good [post from g-truck about mipmaps](http://www.g-truc.net/post-0256.html)

Comment: this is an example from g-truc already. gl-330-fbo-mipmaps.cpp. That tutorial binds both texture unit 0 and sampler before generating mipmaps.

Comment: Right! I've changed the answer, so hopefully it it better.

Comment: Does mipmap generation need any information on sampling /texture parameters (like GL_TEXTURE_LOD_BIAS, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_LOD) ? Because if it does not then I think its safe to assume we dont need to bind the sampler. And about the texture unit: The reason why I asked whether selecting a active texture unit is needed or not is because we know that this texture is already bound to texture unit 0 when we allocated image or specified texture parameters for it. So do we have to specify it again while generating mipmaps?

Comment: Again you can be right. https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object. Sampler has GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL​ and GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL​ params that will be used by glGenerateMipmap so it means that Sampler is important as well. I do not think filtering params are used... probably mipmap generation is implementation dependent.